# String in ONE line

Tags: javascript, string

I need to get a long string to be displayed in a span block in just one line. Without the browser making it into different lines due to space. I have to use JS to make the string appear onclick of a button. This is what I tried but the browser shows it as multiple lines.

```
 var beg= document.formname.elementname.value;
 var oneLine= beg.replace(/[\n]/g, " ");
```

Comment: Browser's do not render line breaks `\r` and `\n` by default. Please include an [mcve] that illustrates the problem. You can use a code snippet (CTRL+M).

Comment: Use CSS to keep it in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS [`white-space`](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=css%20white-space) property with a value of `nowrap` to keep text on one line:

```css
span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<span>This is a really, really long string built to showcase how white-space: nowrap works. Why it is this long, I do not know. But it will definitely overflow the edge of the element. Instead of wrapping, it will simply keep going off to the right, creating a horizontal scrollbar when necessary. Just adding in some additional Lorem Ipsum to ensure that it reaches the edge of the page when this snippet is viewed in full screen.</span>
```

If you really want to do this with JavaScript, you can use
`{element}.style.whiteSpace = "nowrap"`:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
```

```html
<span>This is a really, really long string built to showcase how white-space: nowrap works. Why it is this long, I do not know. But it will definitely overflow the edge of the element. Instead of wrapping, it will simply keep going off to the right, creating a horizontal scrollbar when necessary. Just adding in some additional Lorem Ipsum to ensure that it reaches the edge of the page when this snippet is viewed in full screen.</span>
```